# The fastest way to fetch data from SQL Server and fill an Excel range

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, vsto

I had to fill an Excel range from SQL Server according the following scheme

```
    C1 C2 C3....C29
L1 
L2 
L3 
L4
L5
.....
L120
```

I wondered what could be the fastest way to fetch  each value corresponding to each pair `(Li,Cj)`, value which is stored in SqlServer ?

I could not iterate over each cell.

What could have been your solution ?

I have to say that i managed to retrieve those data in less than 3 seconds

Comment: What's the logic here, you start out going diagonal, but then diverge?

Comment: Sorry i've written in a hurry, consider all the pairs (Li,Cj)
Thanks for your remark

Comment: Can you describe the SQL table in more detail? Right now I'm not sure if the SP returns only 1 row, or a list of rows, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way VSTO provides is a helper function described in this article:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/5cfc24cd-cbeb-4583-b6c8-ad1521e31267

If all you have is an array then you can assign the array directly to the value2 of a range and it populates fairly quickly.

You can set Application.EnableEvents=False and Application.ScreenUpdating=False to speed up your process dramatically. Remember reset them after the process.

Comment: __
Thanks Robert, you are perfectly right concerning the object array when populating the range. indeed it is very fast.
But how do you call the stored procedure which is responsible of returning the value of each pair (L,C)?
__

Comment: In this case I typically call the SP using ADO.Net and then loop the DataTable rows grabbing the ItemArray of the DataRow to build out my larger array. I then poke the array into Value2.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than make an individual stored procedure call for each (L,C) pair, make one call that fetches all the pairs in the table. Hopefully there is no precondition that prevents this from happening. Otherwise, because of the SQL calling overhead alone, you will not be able to get the data back in < 3 seconds. Pull the data in to a SqlDataReader if you can.

Next, populate a 2D array variable, according to the (L,C) relationship in your fetched data. Excel uses a 1-based array, which you can emulate (but not strictly required) as below:

```
// this creates a 1-based 2D array with 5 rows, 2 columns (5,2)
var my2DArray = Array.CreateInstance(
    typeof(object), new int[] { 5, 2 }, new int[] { 1, 1 });
```

After populating the 2D array, set the array to the Excel worksheet. The code would look roughly like below:

```
// not sure what your cell refs are, so I'll be arbitrary...
var rng = myWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "B1");
rng = rng.get_Resize(my2DArray.GetUpperBound(0), my2DArrary.GetUpperBound(1));
rng.Value2 = my2DArray;
```

This should be the fastest way, as compared to setting cell values one by one.